# how to get text of a page inside all nodes

Tags: javascript

I wish to alert all nodes text only. I want to go nested node and get text only

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var th1=0;
        var th2=0;
        var th3=0;
        var th4=0;
        var th5=0;
        var th6=0;
        var tbtn_nbr=0;
        var tspan_nbr=0;
        var tp_nbr=0;
        var ta_nbr=0;
        var tul_nbr=0;
        var tli_nbr=0;

        var title=document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;

        var total_div=document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
        var total_p=document.getElementsByTagName('p').length;
        var total_a=document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;
        var total_span=document.getElementsByTagName('span').length;

        getdata("div", 0);


        function getdata(tag_name, ti)
        {
            //alert(tag_name); alert(ti);

            if(tag_name!='div'){ti--;}

                //alert(ti);

            var total_tag_lenght=document.getElementsByTagName(tag_name).length;

            for(var ti; ti<=Number(total_tag_lenght); ti++){


                var tag_inner=document.getElementsByTagName(tag_name)[ti].innerHTML;
                alert(tag_inner);

                    ti_nbr=ti+1;
                    var words = tag_inner.split(" ");
                    var str=words[0];


                    var nd = str.search("<div");
                    var np = str.search("<p");
                    var na = str.search("<a");
                    var ns = str.search("<span");
                    var nh1 = str.search("<h1");
                    var nh2 = str.search("<h2");
                    var nh3 = str.search("<h3");
                    var nh4 = str.search("<h4");
                    var nh5 = str.search("<h5");
                    var nh6 = str.search("<h6");
                    var nbtn = str.search("<button");
                    var nul = str.search("<ul");
                    var nli = str.search("<li");
                    //alert(np);
                    if(nd>0)
                    {
                        getdata("div", ti_nbr);
                    }

                    else if(np>0)
                    {   //alert("hello");
                        tp_nbr++;
                        //alert(tp_nbr);
                        getdata("p", tp_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(na>0)
                    {   //alert("hello");
                        ta_nbr++;
                        getdata("a", ta_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(ns>0)
                    {   tspan_nbr++;
                        getdata("span", tspan_nbr);
                    }

                    else if(nh1>0)
                    {   th1_nbr++;
                        getdata("h1", th1_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(nh2>0)
                    {   th2_nbr++;
                        getdata("h2", th2_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(nh3>0)
                    {   th3_nbr++;
                        getdata("h3", th3_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(nh4>0)
                    {   th4_nbr++;
                        getdata("h4", th4_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(nh5>0)
                    {   th5_nbr++;
                        getdata("h5", th5_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(nh6>0)
                    {   th6_nbr++;
                        getdata("h6", th6_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(nbtn>0)
                    {   tbtn_nbr++;

                        getdata("button", tbtn_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(nul>0)
                    {   tul_nbr++;
                        getdata("ul", tul_nbr);
                    }
                    else if(nli>0)
                    {   tli_nbr++;
                        getdata("li", tli_nbr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //alert(tag_inner);
                    }






            }



        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jquery, you can select elements using "all" selector $("*").

Then you can iterate on them using "each" function